# Labels for sent messages

Tags: gmail, gmail-labels

I'm a new GMail user, and I'm trying to figure out how to make labels work smoothly.

When I assign a label to an incoming message, it disappears from the inbox and appears in the folder(s) it has been assigned to. This is perfect.

When I assign a label to an *outgoing* message, it stays right where it is. It doesn't disappear from the Sent Mail folder. It doesn't even appear in the assigned folder(s). It just acquires a tag with the label name, which is useless.

I thought that clicking the Move to Inbox button might solve this. I found that it doesn't move a message to the Inbox; it just adds a "Inbox" tag to the subject line, which not only doesn't help, but doesn't even make sense.

I've looked for solutions to this problem in Support, but I didn't find any good ones. One was to assign the label *before* sending the message, which may solve some other problem, but doesn't affect this one. Another was to CC myself on every message I send and label the incoming copy, which sort of solves the problem, but replaces it with an equally bad one: it makes outgoing and incoming messages almost impossible to distinguish.

Comment: How about _Skip the Inbox (Archive it)_?

Answer (score 4):

**Try not to treat Labels as Folders.**

Messages in your Sent folder are just those your archive that you sent yourself (they don't need to have label whatsoever). When you add a label to them, they will appear in that label, and of course they will stay appearing in Sent because you sent them.
(I testes it myself, outgoing mail with a label are showed when you open that label.

What you say about Move to Inbox; Inbox is just a label like another. The only 2 things special about it is that all new incoming messages get the Inbox label (except when you have set up a filter to let messages skip the Inbox) and that the Inbox label is your Gmail homepage.

I hope this helps you, if I did not answer your question then I didn't understand it, please make it more clear than and I'll retry.

Comment: Just to draw more attention to Steven's first point "**Try not to treat Labels as Folders.**"

Answer (score 1):

Upon trying to reproduce your problem, I did the following:

1. Went into *Sent Mail*
2. Took a message that had no label and added a label to it.

When I checked that label, my message did not appear there. The fix to make it appear is to hit the refresh icon (see image below). I'm assuming this was your issue.

[image: Refresh Button - GMail]

Answer (score 1):

Sent mail isn't a folder, it is a special filter where the from equals ME.

Your incoming filter has the mail skip the inbox because that is the option you selected.

While you can and should slap a label onto an outgoing message, it is working exactly as it was designed.

That outgoing message has been tagged with "sent" and "yourlabel". The message can be found under label:sent, it can be found under label:yourlabel; and it can be found under "label:send label:yourlabel"

It should never lose the sent label, nor should you ever want to strip that label from the message.